# How to build a simple application which can capture user input and produce a printable output

Tags: java, web-applications, webforms

We need to build the following application:-

User punches in couple of inputs into a form (e.g. customer name, insurance policy information, bank details and the insurance amount). The application is supposed to take a print copy with 3 perforations which contains the above information (one for the customer, insurance agent and the insurance firm)

The end users in this case (insurance agents) are not tech savvy and would like to have an application with the smallest footprint which can be launched from a CD. Also do note that they might not have an internet connection.

We are looking for ideas on frameworks we should use to build this application. Note: We are proficient in java only. Does this application need to be a web application or a simple html with some pdf generation capability. Looking for suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to enter the information and print the PDF, you can just [create a PDF form with editable fields](http://danilop.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/how-to-create-pdf-forms-with-openoffice/) using OpenOffice, no need to code an application for that.

However if you need to save the data, you then can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to parse the filled form and put its data into a database later.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the 'web' part of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), it might suffice to supply an [applet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) (yes, I did mean **applet** not application) on the CD that is launched using JWS.

As of Java 1.6.0_10+, applets can be dragged from the web page (on the CD) where they reside.  If a dragged applet is configured by JNLP (installed using JWS), it will then install itself into the user's system.

Further, JNLP offers a way for even sand-boxed apps. to use the printer.  See my [demo. of the JNLP PrintService](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#prs) for more details on that.